# Tuning performance in mysql with paging function

Tags: mysql, performance, pagination

Anyone can help me to tuning performance in mysql. Currently, I'm writing a paging function with number of records about 10,000 with page size per page is 20 records. With an pagination link structure and table structure like this: 
`Prev [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] … [20] … [40] Next`

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id`               VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `title`            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `content`          TEXT         NOT NULL,
  FULLTEXT INDEX (title, content)
) ENGINE=Mroonga CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Any way to implement paging function to get the best performance. Can you give me some samples for this.

Comment: SO is not a "do my coding for me" website. Add your code to your question and describe where you are stuck. If you don't have code, google for code, adept it to your problem/query, try it, and then add your code to your question and describe where you are stuck. There are about 100000 code examples out there (basically: use `offset $a limit 20` where `$a` is `20*(pagenumber-1)`), even in the mysql documentation. Add your language (e.g. php), and you will find ready-to-use code/plugins that have even already done the whole coding for you, including the "prev [1] [2]..." part. Just choose any.

Comment: 40 pages hence is probably unrealistic.  See [_this_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) on why "pagination via offset" is bad, plus a workaround.

Comment: `VARCHAR(100)` as a `PRIMARY KEY`?  What kind of values are in it?

Comment: If the `title` is unique, why have a `id` also?